# How to examine query for grid view?

Tags: collection, grid, query

I can get the base query for a given grid view by calling `var_dump` in `Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Myaction_Grid`

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    ...
    var_dump($collection->getSelect()->__toString());
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

...but this returns a "base" query *before* any pagination or filters are applied in creating the grid view. I'd like to be able to examine the query that is actually used to generate a specific grid view. Reason being is that while executing this base query in MySQL returns results I'd expect, the grid view in Magento does not, and I'd like to see what's actually in use.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run getSelect on collection at any given moment. Display it immediately BEFORE the pagination is displayed (in .phtml file). Don't forget that many functions use objects as reference and even though it looks its just a parameter those functions actually update the collection that gets passed to them.

Comment: Adding `var_dump($this->getCollection()->getSelect()->__toString());` to app/design/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml was just what I was looking for. Thanks.